# Multiple-condition gridview filtering

Tags: asp.net, gridview, filter

What would be the best way to provide web users with a possibility to easily filter multi-paged ASP .NET gridviews (**>**, **<**, **==**, **!=**, **like**, etc. by a number of text / number / date fields) with a minimum customization on the server side?

I found one control that looks interesting (http://ammar.tawabini.com/2010/09/gridview-ajax-filter.html) but I'm wondering if there's some solution, which is more known / used / widespread / accepted by the community.

Comment: I doubt you'll find consensus on this. I looked at the "amar.tawabini" solution. Technically, it is great, but the UI seems very programmer oriented, especially regarding the dates.  For example, most users will not understand "Created On >= {t - m(8)}".

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has awesome grid with filter builder: http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Filtering/FilterBuilder.aspx

Comment: Looks awesome but costs hundreds of bucks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datasource controls you can use WhereParameters.  [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.whereparameters.aspx) --  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.whereparameters.aspx)

You can use [ControlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx) to populate from values in your search form.

All this can be done with out any code behind.  Do not confuse this with being easier or simpler but I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a standard way where everything needs to be developed from scratch and I am more interested in solutions that can considerably reduce the amount of manual work - take a look at the gridview ajax filter or DevExpress filter builder.